# Wordpress Login and Register page help!

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

How to create custom login and register page in wordpress? I want to show the login and register page in the current template itself. Is there anyway to show these pages in the content area of the site?

Comment: "Wordpress Custom Login Pages" is a good plugin. We can configure the header and footer for our login and register page. It looks good and I hope it work as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was installed a plugin called [Custom Login Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-login-pages/) and set the header and footer in the login page. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.optiniche.com/blog/297/custom-login-registration-pages/) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I m looking for a custom login page that will override the current wordpress login page. I want to create it as a page in wordpress so that it will show up in the content area.

Thanks

Comment: Is this more what you had in mind? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-login-widget/  It creates a login widget that you can integrate in your theme, rather than having the login form on a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it by yourself.

See [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) for more info. Especially [wp_signon](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) and [wp_create_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) functions.